# How to register dll on win 7 64-bit processor

Tags: dll, 64-bit, regsvr32, dllregistration

Dear All,
         I'm facing problem while registering dll on windows 7 64-bit processor, for that i already use this following code(regsvr32 dllname) but it's giving error message so ur having any idea please share with me